# Device orientation alpha doesn't return value on every angle

Tags: javascript, android-orientation, device-orientation

Some device not return every angle value on change alpha of deviceorientation.
code as below:

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(eventData) {
  // gamma is the left-to-right tilt in degrees, where right is positive
  var tiltLR = eventData.gamma;
  var absolute = eventData.absolute;
  document.getElementById("r4").innerHTML = absolute;
  // beta is the front-to-back tilt in degrees, where front is positive
  var tiltFB = eventData.beta;
  // alpha is the compass direction the device is facing in degrees
  var dir = eventData.alpha
    // call our orientation event handler
  deviceOrientationHandler(tiltLR, tiltFB, dir);
}, false);
```

Device whose `eventData.absolute` returns `undefined` has alpha which works fine, but device whose `eventData.absolute` returns `true` has alpha which doesn't work fine (alpha returns `0,180,360` which only means that not return every angle like `1,2,3,4...178,179` etc). Is possible to fix this by any Javascript code?